# Student's report database design

Tags: mysql, database

I want to display a table like this 
[image: Report Image]

Generated from three database tables depends on student ID

[image: Table Images]

Is this the best way to insert the students' marks? If I have 5,000 student and 10 subjects and 12 exam in year, I will have more than 500.000 record in table Stu_Marks

Comment: +1. Very well asked question, especially for the first one at StackOverflow. Nicely done! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the tables are normalized. BTW you should also have a student table for student information (name, surname).

Regarding the number of records: what you're referring to is the granularity of the data and yours is related to the tuple {student, subject, exam}. If you want to store information for every single student vote, there's no way to avoid a table of 500,000 records.

Comment: Yes i have a table for student info. is this number "500,000 yr" of records is normal in table Stu_Marks ?

Comment: For the table stu_marks yes: every table is a relation-> students table relate every student with its attributes by the primary key. In your case the primary key for relation stu_marks is {student, subject, exam} and you must have one record for every instance of the primary key. So one record for every combination of student, subject and exam.

Comment: yes dear i know that .. i asked about size of data .. it is normal or huge ?? after 4 years i will have more than 2 million record in one table

Comment: What I'm trying to explain to you is that 'normal' and 'huge' are words that have no meaning here: if you want to storage that information, you will have more than 2 million records in that table. It's how RDBMS work, it's not possible to avoid it.

Comment: Don't worry about the number of rows. Rows are cheap.

Comment: Emil Vikström :D But if it slow the database connection .. it will be expensive :(

Comment: Again, you don't alternatives if you wanna use a RDBMS